# Google Gmail API v1 - Error on setting SendAs

Tags: gmail-api, google-api-dotnet-client, service-accounts, google-workspace

**End Point:**

```
https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/settings/sendAs/create
```

**Error:**

```
Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
Custom from requires smtpMsa configuration [400]
Errors [
    Message[Custom from requires smtpMsa configuration] Location[ - ] Reason[invalidArgument] Domain[global]
]
```

We have an app that sets SendAs address of a user using service credentials.

It been working on all users, and for some reason throwing that error on one user. 
This user was created less than 24hrs ago using Cloud Directory Sync (GCDS) via Active Directory.

And the alias we are using is same username with our secondary domain. Which does not require setting up smtpMsa.

So default emails is user@PrimaryDomain.org.

We are getting error when we create new alias called user@SecondaryDomain.org

Any pointers - what could be the issue?

Note that, we tested this on other users, and it's still working.
We deleted the alias on that account and created the alias again - it worked without any issues.

Thanks

Comment: We just tested by adding the alias manually from Gmail. Alias was added without issues, but when we tried updating the email to set as the default address, it is throwing the exact same error. Uses https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/settings/sendAs/update end point to change the secondary SendAs email as IsDefault.

Comment: Tried updating only the signature using the API, same error.

Comment: Apparently this occurs every no and then.
Fixes by it self after waiting for a day or 2